# Prevent window scrolling without using overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm trying to disable scrolling on my page and I want to do it without using overflow:hidden because it repaints the whole page when I disable the overflow:hidden.
Since I want do disable it also for touch devices I need something more than just disabling the mouse movement and if I disable the touchMove then I'm not able to scroll horizontally or perform any other movements with touch.
Maybe by using   window.onscroll = function(){//some code here} ??
Any hint how to do this?

Comment: how can `overflow: hidden` destroy performance?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say that it repaints the whole page when I disable the overflow:hidden and this is really bad.

Comment: A single repaint costs nothing when compared to triggering a function on each scroll event.

Comment: Is not the cost but the visual effect that is bad.